# http vs https Extra characters added in address bar (MEAN stack)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ssl, heroku, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack app that I am trying to develop. I have been working with amazon aws and hosting the app there. But I was curious about heroku and decided to try the app there. I haven't added and SSL cert. for my amazon page so all I have is http://

I am still somewhat of an intermediate when it comes to heroku. Once I was able to move the app over to heroku I noticed that I was getting a bunch of extra characters in the address bar.

This is what the "working" address bar would look like when I would click a link
eg.

```
http://www.website.com/#/register/
```

But when I moved to heroku I would have extra characters put inside the address bar

eg.

```
https://www.website.com/#!/#%2Fregister
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the SSL (https) Could some explain whats going on here. Because my pages do not load anymore. I have gotten some clues through google. Maybe it has nothing to do with SSL cert... either way a good explanation would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http -> https doesn't change the URL at all. But since `/register` is encoded as `%2Fregister`, and you went from hash to hashbang, I'm going to guess that some of your dependencies and/or settings aren't the same version between your dev/AWS and Heroku environments.

Comment: Ah! So I am guessing it probably was when I npm installed dependencies. It maybe updated to the latest and now I am getting conflicts?

Comment: That's my guess. You might want to look at your package.json to see if you are specifying ranges or specific versions, or lock them down.

Comment: You were correct! I posted an update/answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So mherzig was correct. I had missing dependencies for some reason they didn't install when I ran npm install from the package.json file. So for future generations reading this. Make sure your node_modules folder has all the dependencies there for your app.

Thanks again mherzig for pointing me in the right direction.